# Visual Basic - Jimmy Johns Order Form; Dealing with about 200 checkboxes

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2012, checkbox

I'm working on a Jimmy Johns Order Form for a high school project and I have about 200 CheckBoxes on one of the forms. They are numbered completely out of order and I was wondering if there was an easier way to analyze all the CheckBoxes instead of checking each CB and taking in the value.

Please see the pictures below to further assist you. I have both forms, the form where the user selects the CBs (the first link) and the form where the information should be displayed (the second link).

[Choose Sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QBu5.jpg)

[Confirm Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNnkO.png)

Feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: You could create an array of checkBoxes and place them on the form programmatically rather than making them by hand, that way you could check their value with a simple loop.

Comment: How have you named the checkBoxes?  They shouldn't be purely numbered.  They should be named descriptively.  For example: `chbSodaPop1`, `chbChocChipCookie1`, etc.  There will still be numbers, given you've got 6 copies of the same thing for whatever reason... but 6 is a pretty manageable number.

Comment: @nhgrif The form was set up without thinking about the code so the CBs are numbered as such: CheckBox21, CheckBox43, etc. There is no particular order.

Comment: You can rename the checkboxes.

Comment: Yes, but the CBs in the picture are not the only ones. There are more CBs on another panel which id hidden by default and only shows if you choose a Slim Sandwich. There are about 200 total CBs. I was looking for a simpler way, if there is no other way, I could rename it.

Comment: Take the time now to rename them all, or make a checkBox array. Any other solution would be a hack and result in horrible code later on. For example if you persisted with the current names, anyone reading your code would have no idea what each checkBox is for, including yourself.

Comment: Yes, I do realize that. I guess I'll rename them now. Or I could also delete them and create a CheckBox array. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use `CheckedListBox`'s? It seems more appropriate in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the CBs of a panel (or anything else) like this:

```
For Each c As Control In Panel.Controls
   If (TypeName(c) = "CheckBox") then
       'Do whatever you want
   End If
Next
```

### Update:

As @Styxxy suggested, you could use `Panel.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)` too.

```
For Each c As Control In Panel.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
       'Do whatever you want
Next
```

Comment: @Sarmadjaved : I'd use `Panel.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)`, that way you have it already typed and you don't need to check for the typename.